# style switcher in jQuery without page refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have now one page which has a default.css style
I have one style1.css file and another one is style2.css file.
I have one UI dropdownlist which has two options.

When I select one then apply style1.css and same thing for other.

The page should not be refresh.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have no specific context I would suggest looking into using jQuery [**toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Say you have HTML like this where the div in this example uses a default style `style1` and a button will switch out styles:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="style1"></div>
<button id="myButton">Switch Styles</button>
```

In addition to `style1` you have also another style defined, say `style2` likes this:

```
.style1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.style2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

​To switch them when clicking on the button using the `toggleClass()` method you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").on("click", function(){
        $("#myDiv").toggleClass("style2");
    });
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mY8e/)

You can off course trigger the toggle from anywhere, not just the button, this was only an example.

Comment: And if you wanted a whole different theme for a page or section, set a class on <body> or a parent element and have a single style sheet with information for all. body.theme1 a {} for all links in themes for instance

Comment: @joevallender: +1 thanks. Exactly i want to do what u say and i done it.

Answer (score 0):

look at http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/